# Simple package.json/git tag version bump

Tags: git, npm

```
$ npm version 10.20.00.1
npm version 10.20.00.1
npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor | preminor | prepatch | prerelease [--preid=<prerelease-id>] | from-git]
npm ERR! (run in package dir)
npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (6.4.1)
npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions
```

So the above worked before. I'm guessing this has to do with a new NPM version (running 6.4.1).

So what I'm trying to do, is just , simply, bump the version number in my `package.json` file and also do a `git tag`. How does one do this in the new NPM version?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Just realised that it's strict with only allowing semver format. Oh well, I'll just have to do this manually with the version I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm version patch
```

or

```
npm version patch --no-git-tag-version
```

will bump it once.  npm version only supports three numbers in your version: major, minor, and patch.  if you want to do a specific number you can try

```
npm install -g json
json -I -f package.json -e "this.version='1.1.1.1.1'"
```

which will replace whatever is in the version key of your package.json with 1.1.1.1.1